# Passing a HashMaps value's to a url

Tags: java, json, serialization, hashmap

I have data stored in HashMaps and I would like to pass this data to a url but I want it to remained grouped together. I am thinking of serializing the HashMaps and then passing that data to PHP and then unserailzing. My second alternative will be passing the data to JSON and then passing it into a url.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this or a better solution?

Example:

```
//Has Data added to hash map
HashMap hashmap1=new HashMap();

//Has Data added to hash map
HashMap hashmap2=new HashMap();

//dateEncoded Method
//Will encode data by serializing it or passing it to JSON
 String data = URLEncoder.encode(dataEncoded(hashmap1), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("10", "UTF-8");  
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(dataEncoded(hashmap2), "UTF-8");  

        // Send data  
        URL url=new URL("http://localhost/index.php?"+data);
```

Comment: what exactly is the question? Have you looked at Jackson ObjectMapper?

Comment: What kind of data is included in these maps? If it's various name value pairs, they might be appropriate as URL query parameters. If the maps represent some structured data e.g. an object, JSON might be a better representation. I need more info about what you're trying to send.

Comment: Why is there even php tag attached to this question?

Comment: The question is what is the best solution for passing all the data from a hashmap as query to a url.

Comment: The data is mixed, integers, strings, floats, etc.

Comment: Why are you using a hashmap as a key in your HTTP parameters? Also, is your variable to store the hashmap going to be the same each time?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter name/value pairs will work just fine, as long as you assume that all the pairs you find need to end up in the map.